# Implementing checkmate in python

Tags: python, chess

I have been trying to figure out what the wrong part in here is and I am honestly not doing well. This is really confusing, but the pieces on the board (usually the kings) keep moving away from their original positions although they're not supposed to whenever this function runs. Please keep in mind that this is incomplete. I'm going to explain what most of the variables in my code are at the end of this post. Thank you so much for reading this!

```
def checkmate(self, other):
        temp_board = Board()
        temp_coords = tuple(self.initial_coords)
        coordinates = [(self.initial_coords[0] + 1, self.initial_coords[1]),
                       (self.initial_coords[0] - 1, self.initial_coords[1]),
                       (self.initial_coords[0], self.initial_coords[1] + 1),
                       (self.initial_coords[0], self.initial_coords[1] - 1),
                       (self.initial_coords[0] + 1, self.initial_coords[1] + 1),
                       (self.initial_coords[0] - 1, self.initial_coords[1] - 1),
                       (self.initial_coords[0] + 1, self.initial_coords[1] -1),
                       (self.initial_coords[0] - 1, self.initial_coords[1] + 1)]
        coordinates = [coordinate for coordinate in coordinates if max(coordinate) < 8 and min(coordinate) >= 0]
        returned = True
        for coordinate in coordinates:
            temp_coords = tuple(self.initial_coords)
            temp_board.board = list(other.board)
            if temp_board.board[coordinate[1]][coordinate[0]] == ' ' or temp_board.board[coordinate[1]][coordinate[0]] != ' ' and temp_board.board[coordinate[1]][coordinate[0]].image not in Piece.SIDE[self.side]:
                if temp_board.board[coordinate[1]][coordinate[0]] == ' ':
                    temp_board.board[temp_coords[1]][temp_coords[0]], temp_board.board[coordinate[1]][coordinate[0]] = temp_board.board[coordinate[1]][coordinate[0]], temp_board.board[temp_coords[1]][temp_coords[0]]
                else:
                    temp_board.board[self.initial_coords[1]][self.initial_coords[0]] = ' '
                    temp_board.board[coordinate[1]][coordinate[0]] = self
                temp_coords = coordinate
                is_mate = self.check_baton(other)
                print('is_mate = ', is_mate)
                if any(is_mate):
                    returned = False
                    break
                
        return returned
```

So self.initial_coords is a variable which stores the current coordinates at which each piece resides. In this case, we are working with the king (it's the instance of that class) so these are just the current coordinates belonging to the king. The list which is called coordinates just stores all of the places that the king may be capable of moving to. Other is an instance of the class Board and it has the original and main board that I use to display all of the pieces .board is an attribute to each instance of the class board and it's basically a list which contains the positions of all pieces. Piece.SIDE is a dictionary which contains this: SIDE = {'white': ['♜', '♞', '♝', '♛', '♚', '♟'], 'black': ['♖', '♘', '♗', '♕', '♔', '♙']} and self.side would return either 'white' or 'black' depending on the colour of the king. And that's about it. If you need anything more then please let me know. Thank you so much for going through this and trying to help me. Here's my full code if you'd like to view it: https://pastebin.com/cNWESrmU
and you'll find this function at somewhere around line 207.

Comment: It sounds like you are not creating a real/deep copy of the board. Therefore all you do on the temp board will actually be on the real board. Try using deep copy of the board instead and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding